# Using localStorage to save an answer to a sum

Tags: jquery, sum, local-storage

I have a sum in my javascript, but I want to save the answer using localStorage but I'm not sure how to go about it?

My sum itself is:

```
var val4 = ((655+(val3*4.35) + (val2*4.7) - (val1*6.8))*1.55)+500;
```

The sum itself is right and comes out with the correct answer, I just want that answer (val4) to be stored in localStorage.

Comment: So there is no error? Here is a good start: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: @MonkeyZeus http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('sum', val4)`?

Comment: @PranavRam I was wondering how long it would take for someone to post that link =)

Comment: @ArunPJohny wow, it was that easy. Can't believe I couldn't figure that one out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage allows you to store key value pairs. To store something to local storage, use

```
window.localStorage.setItem(key,value);
```

You can retiree an item from localStorage by

```
localStorage.getItem(key);
```

localStorage is an HTML5 feature and not all browsers support it. You would better check if the browser support localStorage before attempting to read or write to it. Also, localStorage support only Strings for key and value. So you must covert your integer to string while writing to localStorage and string to int while reading back. Every browser has set some predefined quita for local storage (typically 5 MB) . If you exceed it, any attempt to write to localStorage will raise an exception. The code below handles these concerns.

```
/*key should be String, value can be any Javascript object */
function writeToLocalStorage(key,value) 
{
  if(typeof(Storage) == 'undefined')
  {
  alert("This feature is not supported by the browser you are using currently");
    return false;
  }

  value = JSON.stringify(value); //serializing non-string data types to string

   try
   {
       window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
   }
   catch (e) 
   {
       if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
          alert('Local storage Quota exceeded! .Clearing localStorage');
          localStorage.clear();
          window.localStorage.setItem(key, value); //Try saving the preference again
          }
   }

   return true;
}




function readFromLocalStorage(key)
{
 if(typeof(Storage) == 'undefined')
  {
   //Broswer doesnt support local storage
   return false;
  }

 value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
 return value;

}
```